# Preview.app and text highlight opacity

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, adobe

I am working with a PDF file version 1.7 using Preview.app on my Mac. In the file there is some highlighted text that cannot be seen since the color is completely opaque. What can I do to view the text? In other files it works just fine as long as the PDF file is version 1.4.

When I open it in Adobe, I can see the text with the highlight like it should be, but I don't want to switch to Adobe. Is there a way to solve it? Or maybe a way convert the PDF file from version 1.7 to 1.4?